# How to find the rate at which something is increasing?

Tags: calculus

Certain pieces of antique furniture increased very rapidly in price in the 1970s and 1980s. For example, the value of a particular rocking chair is well approximated by

V = 105 (1.75)^t, 
where V is in dollars and t is the number of years since 1975. Find the rate, in dollars per year, at which the price is increasing.

rate = _____ dollars/year

1. I have tried taking the derivative.
2. I tried tried plugging in 5 for t.
   I'm not sure exactly how to approach this problem, the methods I'm trying are not working

Comment: If we are not told at what time we want the rate of increase, our answer will have to be given in terms of $t$. Differentiate, maybe using the fact that $(105)(1.75^t)=(105)e^{t\ln(1.75)}$.

Comment: Why would you plug in $5$ for $t$? The value of $t$ is $0$ in 1975; $t = 5$ would give you the year 1980, which does not seem to have any special significance in the question.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, for $a>0$, the derivative of $a^{t}$ is $$\frac{d}{dt}a^{t}=a^{t}\ln(a)$$ Here's the proof for this formula: we will start by proving the derivative formula $$\frac{d}{dt}\log_{a}(t)=\frac{1}{t\ln(a)}$$

Using the change of base formula, $$\log_{a}(t)=\frac{\ln(t)}{\ln(a)}$$ we have $$\frac{d}{dt}\log_{a}(t)=\frac{1}{\ln(a)}\cdot \frac{1}{t}=\frac{1}{t\ln(a)}$$  Now, for any invertible function $f$, the equation $(f\circ f^{-1})(x)=x$ holds for all x in the domain of $f^{-1}$.  The Chain Rule then yields $$f'(f^{-1}(x))(f^{-1})'(x)=1$$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f^{-1}$.  Equivalently, $$(f^{-1})'(x)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$$  Thus, since $a^{t}$ is the inverse function to $\log_{a}(t)$, we have $$\frac{d}{dt}a^{t}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a^{t}\ln(a)}}=a^{t}\ln(a)$$ For your problem, Chris, use $a=1.75$.